# Azure: Provisioning of virtual machine fails.

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to provision Azure Virtual Machines to the same availability set one after the other. I see this error when trying to a provision in Australia East.

```
 Provisioning failed. Allocation failed. Please try reducing the VM size or 
 number of VMs, retry later, or try deploying to a different Availability Set 
 or different Azure location.. AllocationFailed
```

Comment: You probably need to reach out to support, to check your core allocation for Australia East. There's really nothing that can be done here at StackOverflow.

Comment: I checked out the core allocation and we don't seem to be hitting our limits.

Answer (score 1):

This error means you are try to adding a big size VM to the Availability set, the VM size bigger than other VMs, that host does not support this VM size.

We should **stop** all the VMs in the availability set. Then add this new VM to it, then start the other VMs.

Here a [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/shwetanayak/2016/12/30/learnings-azure-availability-sets/) about add VM to Azure availability set, please refer to it.

---

Update:

Please try to create new VM and at the same time to create Availability set, like this:
[image]

Comment: So It seems to be working for us in other regions. Also, This error seems to be popping up even when I add a VM to a newly created Availability set.

Comment: @nwarriorch How about via azure portal to create VM, and at the same time to create availability set? Please try it:)

Comment: @nwarriorch Have you try to use other location to test it?

Comment: @nwarriorch Have you create a VM without availability set, just a VM(use that VM size)?

Comment: @nwarriorch To troubleshoot this issue more efficiently, could you please show me your steps to create availability and add a VM to it, thanks:)